# How to prevent multiple returns inside for loop in php?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Im trying to insert multiple fileds with same name, but "echo" is returning multiple feedbacks.For example:Success, Success.... or multiple Empty Fields. Can you please help to insert datas and return only Success or Empty Fields? I appreciate your help!

```
global $conn;
if (isset($_POST['languages']) && isset($_POST['knowledge'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $id = $_SESSION["id"];
        @$languages = $_POST['languages'][$i];
        @$knowledge = $_POST['knowledge'][$i];
        if (!empty($languages)) {
            $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO languages (userid, languages,kn_level) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            $sql->bindParam(1, $id);
            $sql->bindParam(2, $languages);
            $sql->bindParam(3, $knowledge);
            if ($sql->execute()) {
                echo "Success";
                //header("location:/settings");
            } 
        }else{
            echo "Empty Fields";
        }
    }
    
}





$(document).on('click', '#langIdButton', function(e) {
        var data = $("#langSkills").serializeArray();
        
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            url: 'settings/addlanguage',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == "Success") {
                    $('#lang_response').html(data).show()

                } else {
                    $('#lang_response').html(data).show()
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Set a flag inside the loop, and check the flag outside the loop to decide what to echo. If you echo inside the loop, you will get one response for each iteration.

Comment: So you only want to know if _all_ the queries succeeded? What about if some are empty but others are not? Should it then insert just the ok data and not the rest, or should it not insert any rows at all? And what feedback would you want? Surely you'd want to know precisely which data was faulty, and if there was more than one faulty one. Please explain specifically what output you would expect in each scenario, because I don't think you've really thought it through.

Comment: Rather than using the error supression `@` (always **V.v.Bad**) test for the existance of an occurance properly ( See `isset()` )

Comment: Surely, if you tested that `count($_POST['languages']) == count($_POST['knowledge'])` and then control your loop using the `count($_POST['languages'])` rather than an arbitrary `10` iterations. Most of the issues would all disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your code to **first test** and after that insert, depending on how many good values there are.

```
//test if there is a id
if(empty($_SESSION["id"])){
   //echo some error message
   die;
   }

//get the length of languages, create a empty result array and fetch the id
$len    = count( $_POST['languages'] );
$result = Array();
$id     = $_SESSION["id"];

 //test if $_POST['languages']) has the same length as $_POST['knowledge']
if( $len === count( $_POST['knowledge'] )){
    // if they are test each value
   foreach( $_POST['languages'] as $key => $language ){
       // first test the language. If empty: skip
      if($language === ''){
        continue;  
        }
       // then test the corresponding knowledge. If empty: skip
      if($_POST['knowledge'][$key] === ''){
        continue;  
        }
       // if both good: add the values to result
      $result[]=[ $id, $language, $_POST['knowledge'][$key] ];
    }
  //if the are not, something went wrong
else{
  //echo some error
    die;
    }
 //count the good values
$isgood = count( $result );
```

After testing, `$isgood` has a number from `0` (all wrong) to `$len` (all good). You can then choose what you do when not all data was good: insert only the good ones, or insert nothing.

```
 // stop when not all good
if($isgood !== $len){
    echo "Empty Fields";
    die;
    }
 // ===== OR =======
 // if nothing good, stop, else insert only the good ones
if($isgood === 0){
    echo "Empty Fields";
    die;
    }

$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO languages (userid, languages,kn_level) VALUES (?,?,?)");
foreach($result as $values){
   $sql->bindParam(1, $values[0] );
   $sql->bindParam(2, $values[1] );
   $sql->bindParam(3, $values[2] );
   $sql->execute();
   }          
echo 'Succes';
```

Comment: Michel, this is perfect buddy! Thank you very much!